# Unable to generate sequence wise unique number along with day in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, numbers

in my code I have a product uploading system, I want every time I upload a product it would have a unique product code.I'm using PHP CodeIgniter framework. I've done everything e.g the end two digits of the year and the count of days out of 365 days but unable to generate serial number like 1865001 then 1865002 then 1865003.

Below is the code of my controller

```
public function view(){

         $data['subview'] = 'admin/parts/user_list';
         $data['title'] = 'User Overview';
         $data['users'] = $this->Users_model->get_users();

        //Code Generator
         $this->load->helper('string');

         $y= substr(date('Y'),2);
         $t = date('z') + 1;    

         $data['codes'] = $y.$t;
         $this->load->view('admin/__layout_admin.php', $data);
         print_r($data['codes']);

       }
```

The current output is 1865.
I want it should be like 1865001,1865002,1865003,1865004.
Please help me doing this.

Comment: If you need your code increments by one, you will need to store the last code in somewhere, like a database, and reset it when a new day starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, numbers should be like 18065001, note the zero between 18 and 65, cause when you reach day 100th you will keep the length. 
Also, you will need a daily counter to generate sequential part (001, 002, ..), I would store that counter in a database so u can update every time u generate a product and reset it when a new day coming up.

So the code could be something like:

```
public function view(){

     $data['subview'] = 'admin/parts/user_list';
     $data['title'] = 'User Overview';
     $data['users'] = $this->Users_model->get_users();

    //Code Generator
     $this->load->helper('string');

     $y= substr(date('Y'),2);
     $t = date('z') + 1; 
     // fill one one zero if year is less than 100
     $t =  2 == strlen($t) ? '0' . $t : $t;
     $counter = $this->ProductCounter_model->get_counter();
     $data['codes'] = $y . $t . sprintf('%03d', $counter + 1);
     $this->load->view('admin/__layout_admin.php', $data);
     print_r($data['codes']);

   }
```

So in `$data['counter']` you will receive the current counter and when you store the product you should update the counter in the database. Don't forget to reset the counter to zero at midnight.

And if it is not strictly necessary to have correlative numbers (001, 002, 003) I will use the number of seconds from midnight which would simplify the process and avoid to save and reset the counter and also pass it as a parameter in data, in that case, you can change this line:

```
$data['codes'] = $y . $t. sprintf('%05d', echo time() -
strtotime("today"));
```

You need 5 space for the greatest number of second from one day, 86400 seconds.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecomm\application\controllers\users.php on line 45

This is what i get

Comment: Can you paste here line 45 of your users.php?

Comment: I have actually solved that error by storing the time() in  $time variable.

But what I want is generate 001,002 I don't want to store seconds. In the code, you have to try to store seconds. I want number just... I just want to upload products and this generated codes gonna be the unique so don't want the seconds bu t001,002,003 would be better

Comment: You have to take into account also that $data['counter'] has to be setup, if you want just to test it, please add $data['counter'] = 13; for instance after line $data['users'] = $this->Users_model->get_users(); you have to get 18067014

Comment: So if you want 001, 002, ... you need that counter I suggest you in the example before I talked of seconds because you need to now the previous number and increment it

Comment: that's the code I wanted but don't figure out how to show the $data['counter'] dynamically

Comment: My suggestion is create a ProductCounter_model, in the same way you have $this->Users_model->get_users(); and then read the counter from database, so $counter = $this->ProductCounter_model->get_counter(); And after creating the product you should have another method to update the counter like $this->Users_model->increment();

Comment: Yeah, thanks, great answer and best suggestions.Thank you so much

Comment: Thnak you so much